# How to pass arguments to homebrew service

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, beanstalkd

I have installed beanstalkd using homebrew but am unable to increase the maximum job size.

This is normally done by passing the -z argument as "-z byte_size"

All attempts to edit the formula for myself have failed to increase the job size as needed.

How do I successfully pass the -z argument in homebrew to increase the maximum job size.

I have tried using "brew edit beanstalkd" and modified the file adding a second "string" value with the -z 10000000 but this didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 4):

Brew maintains a `.plist` config file under every package it installs, usually at `/usr/local/Cellar/$pkgName/$pkgVersion/homebrew.mxcl.$pkgName.plist` or `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/$pkgName/$pkgVersion/homebrew.mxcl.$pkgName.plist` for newer Macs, and in this file you can set arguments for the specific service. For example, set port 3307 for mysql:

```
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
    <string>--port=3307</string>
</array>
```

By the way, when starting this service, brew will read it and copy it to somewhere like `/usr/local/opt/$pkgName/homebrew.mxcl.$pkgName.plist`, edit this copied version of `.plist` doesnt help.

To get the accurate package-installed path, run `brew info pkgName`.